# WebApplicationInitializer container.addFilter() returns null

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-applications

I am creating a `REST`-based web application with `AngularJS` as front end and `REST`-based backend (with `Spring 4`). I am following the code-based configuration approach found here: [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)

When I run the project on the server, I get a null value in the line:

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter =  container.addFilter("prerender", seoFilter);
```

What am I missing? I am a bit new to creating web-apps from scratch using annotations.

Here is the class in question:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
appContext.setConfigLocation("classpath:MyContext.xml");

ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
dispatcher.addMapping("/api/*");

com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter seoFilter = new com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter();
FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter =  container.addFilter("prerender", seoFilter);
filter.setInitParameter("prerenderToken", "123456789123456789");
filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null , true, "/*");

ServletRegistration.Dynamic initSysConfiguration
        = container.addServlet("initSysConfiguration", new InitSystemConfigurations());
initSysConfiguration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
initSysConfiguration.addMapping("/InitSystemConfigurations");

}
```

This line is give me null

```
com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter seoFilter = new com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter();
```

I tried this,but same result

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter1 =  container.addFilter("prerender",  com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter.class);
```

Comment: Can you share the exception stack trace

Comment: Have you read the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addFilter-java.lang.String-javax.servlet.Filter-) and ruled out all the cases where the `addFilter()` method returns null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the method `addFilter` returns `null` it means there is already [a filter registered](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addFilter(java.lang.String,%20javax.servlet.Filter)) for that name.

> **Returns:**
>   a `FilterRegistration` object that may be used to further configure the given filter, or `null` if this `ServletContext` already contains a complete `FilterRegistration` for a filter with the given `filterName` or if the same filter instance has already been registered with this or another `ServletContext` in the same container

Make sure that you don't have a `web.ml` which already registers this filter.

Another tip instead of implementing `WebApplicationInitializer` yourself extend the [`AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.html) and implement the needed methods.

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(container);

        com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter seoFilter = new com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter();
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter =  container.addFilter("prerender", seoFilter);
        filter.setInitParameter("prerenderToken", "123456789123456789");
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null , true, "/*");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic initSysConfiguration
                = container.addServlet("initSysConfiguration", new InitSystemConfigurations());
        initSysConfiguration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        initSysConfiguration.addMapping("/InitSystemConfigurations");

    }

    protected WebApplicationContext createServletApplicationContext() {
        XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.setConfigLocation("classpath:MyContext.xml");
        return appContext;
    }

    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/api/*"};
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by running maven command `mvn clean`, I dont know some thing was wrong somewhere and giving me strange behaviour. I m not sure what i learn from this problem :(

Thanks for your help.